# Node child process does not die when parent dies

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

I have the following node script on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (armv7l cpu) which launches a python script and reads data that the python script writes to `stdout`. The python process contains an infinite loop and continually scans the environment for certain events and prints them out.

It works but if the node process dies, the python process keeps running. How do I make the python process die when the node process dies?

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const pyprog = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['/my/code/test.py']);

pyprog.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});

pyprog.stderr.on('data', err => {
    console.error('error:', err);
});

pyprog.stdout.on('end', () => {
    console.log('python process ended');
});
```

I would figure child processes would die when the parent does so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: What OS are you using? According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) that should be the case unless `options.detached` is provided, with some differences between Windows and non-Windows

Comment: Good question, it's ubuntu, I'll update the post